# Only Select one radio button but they cant have the same name because of the PHP

Tags: php, html

I have 2 radio button and i only want one two be selected at the same time but i cant give them the same name because of my php function that does something by the name of the selected button what can i do to only select one or how can i change my php function ?

```
<Form method ="Post" action ='PutzauftragSpeichern.php?PutzauftragID'>
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='Fertig1' value= 'Pendent'/> Noch Nicht Fertig <br />
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='Fertig' value= 'Fertig' /> Fertig <br /><br />
<Input type = 'submit' Name ='submit' value= 'Weiter' ><br />
<form>
```

This is my PHP Function:

```
if (isset($_POST['Fertig1'])){
header("refresh:0;url=NeuerAuftrag.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['Fertig'] )) {
$RadioUpdate = "UPDATE Putzauftrag SET Status = 'Check' WHERE PutzauftragID 
= $PutzauftragID";
mysqli_query($db,$RadioUpdate);
echo "<h1>Speichern erfolgreich</h1>";
header("refresh:0;url=NeuerAuftrag.php");
}
```

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Multiple line breaks are not a substitute for CSS margins / line-height

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must give them the same name. That is how radio button groups work in HTML.

Use the *value* to determine which was checked.

```
if (!isset($_POST['Fertig'])){
    # Handle the error state of neither button being checked
} else {
    $fertig = $_POST['Fertig'];
    if ($fertig == "Pendent") {
        # Do action for Pendent
    } elseif  ($fertig == "Fertig") {
        # Do action for Fertig
    } else {
        # Handle the error state of the client sending data that you did not expect (e.g. by modifying the form with the DOM inspector or bypassing it entirely and making the request with cURL)
    }
}
```